# Git project is already modified, when cloned from scratch

Tags: git

I just checked out another copy of a large project in /tmp, and, immediately after the clone, I did a diff and there are uncommmited changes. How can I have uncommited changes in a freshly clone project.

Just to be sure, I cloned it a second time, into another directory. Same thing.

What's going on? I would think there is no way to clone uncommitted changes.

It's not line feeds, or permissions. It looks like a reasonable set of changes to the file.

I doubt it matters, but I'm on a mac.

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
git reset --hard
```

Did not fix anything, nor did  `git checkout -- path/to/file.java`

Output of git status:

```
% git status
On branch xx
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/xx'.

Changes not staged for commit:
   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
   (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   path/to/file.java
```

Comment: "I doubt it matters, but I'm on a mac." MacOS has a case insensitive filesystem, which can be repsonsible for this sort of behavior (if your repository has files that differ in case only, one file can overwrite another). Can you show us the output of `git status`?

Comment: Aha! It looks like you are correct. Looks like the file got renamed from one name, to another, with only one letter changing case. I had looked for that, and missed it, as it's a long name.

Comment: As case is really important here, can you actually copy and paste the verbatim lines and not replace the file name with your own /path/to/file?

Comment: @MarcusMüller That probably would have helped. I was  just trying not to post internal info. But I think we have it nailed down, and it was case related. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, the issue was actually that someone made a copy of a file, and changed the case, but didn't delete the original. This left us with two files in the project that different only by case.